# How should I interpret the results I'm getting from Grad?

Tags: vector-calculus

When I type the following in Mathematica:

```
$Assumptions = (a | b | c | d) ∈ Vectors[3, Reals];
Grad[(b - a)\[Cross](d - c), {a}]
```

I obtain:

> `{(-1)\[Cross](-c + d)}`

but I really don't understand what it means to make the cross product between a scalar and a vector.

Similarly,

```
Grad[(b - a).(d - c), {a}]
```

> `{(-1).(-c + d)}`

What does this mean?

Comment: Basically, it means you do not understand what `Grad` does. Follow [this link](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Grad.html) to learn about `Grad`, and follow [this 2nd link]( http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/UsingAssumptions.html) to learn what functions will use assumptions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issued raised is not really a problem; it is arises from the OP's misunderstanding of the result returned by Mathematica.

Comment: My question is not about whether Grad takes assumptions or not (anyway thanks for pointing it out),but what the returned expression means. Mathematica has accepted that input and given me an answer. Unless there is some bug in Mathematica, I suppose that the response have a meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Grad` does a formal transformation on its 1st input. That means the old programmer's saying "garbage in, garbage out" applies -- when the input has no meaning, neither does the output.

`Grad` treats it 1st argument as if it were a function of the variables given in its 2nd argument. In your case, that means it assumes the 1st argument is a function of `a`. For a function `f` of one variable,

```
 g = Grad[f[a], {a}]
```

gives

> `{Derivative[1][f][a]}`

Therefore, the meaning of

```
Grad[(b - a)\[Cross](d - c), {a}]
```

is the same as the meaning of

```
g /. f -> ((b - #)\[Cross](d - c) &)
```

> `{(-1)\[Cross](-c + d)}`

because

```
{Derivative[1][((b - #)\[Cross](d - c) &)][a]}
```

gives

> `(-1)\[Cross](-c + d)`

This is a purely formal transformation and has no deeper meaning.

The case of where `Dot` replaces `Cross` is totally similar.

Answer (score 2):

Functions, like `Grad`, which do not take an Assumptions options, ignore the value of $Assumptions.  So as far as Mathematica is concerned, you're asking for the gradient in 1 dimension of the cross product of two scalars, and it's doing its best to answer your question.